# Комбинации регулярных выражений (Pattern) Java

Tags: java

Имеется метод String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Допустим мне нужно заменить каждый символ в строке. Следовательно, в **regex** я записываю **"."**.

Если мне нужно заменить каждый символ в строке таким же символом дважды ("а" заменяю на "аа", "в" заменяю на "вв" и так далее), то мне нужно прописать в **replacement** такую комбинацию **"$0$0"**.

Как получилась такая комбинация **"$0$0"**? По ссылке выше такого нету. Не могу понять.

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) есть. Note that backslashes (\\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. **Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above**, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

Comment: А комбинация знака доллара ($) с нулем (0) откуда?

Comment: Все найденное выражение

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("test".replaceAll(".", "$0$0"));
```

Тут надо понимать, что при разборе текста регулярным выражением можно использовать группы. У нас случай простой, и групп в принципе нет. Обращаются к группам по индексу, начиная с единицы.

Вот пример работы с группами:

```
System.out.println("1-2".replaceAll("(\\d)(.*)(\\d)", "$3$2$1"));
```

Мы переставляем первое и последнее число местами. Результат:

```
2-1
```

А что же с `$0`? Это означает, что берётся полное найденное совпадение (если есть).

```
System.out.println("41-2".replaceAll("\\d(\\d)(.*)(\\d)", "$3$2$1 \"$0\""));
```

Результат:

```
2-1 "41-2"
```